# How can I destroy a game object forever?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So, I have this potion. When the player in my game comes in contact with the potion, I want to destroy the potion. However, if the player dies, the scene will reload and the potion will still be in the level. If the player collides with the potion, I don't want them to obtain it. They should only be able to collect the potion once.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;


public class DestroyPotionForever : MonoBehaviour
{
    public bool potionCollide = false;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        
    }
    void OnTriggerEnter(){
        if(potionCollide == false){
            Destroy(gameObject);
            bool potionCollide = true;
        }
    }


    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        
    }
}
```

But...this code doesn't work. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I doesn't work because if you reload the scene, the script restarts and the values are set to the default.

Answer (score 4):

A simple way would be to store whether you had picked up the potion in [PlayerPrefs](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PlayerPrefs.html).

Then you could do something like:

```
void OnTriggerEnter()
{
    if(PlayerPrefs.GetInt("GotPotion", 0) == 0)
    {
        // You didn't get the potion yet, so get it
        Destroy(gameObject);
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt("GotPotion", 1); // got the potion
    }
}
```

Then wherever you spawn your potion, you could have:

```
if(PlayerPrefs.GetInt("GotPotion", 0) == 1)
{
    // Got the potion already, so don't spawn the potion
}
```

Or, you if you put the potion in the scene directly, you could do:

```
void Start()
{
    if(PlayerPrefs.GetInt("GotPotion", 0) == 1)
    {
        // If the potion is already picked up, destroy it
        Destroy(gameObject);
    }
}
```

A **much better way** would be to write your own save system as Antnio Pedro Gonalves Ferreira suggested, but this will get you through the demo phase at least.

Answer (score 2):

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;


public class DestroyPotionForever : MonoBehaviour
{
    public bool potionCollide = false;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        
    }
    void OnTriggerEnter(){
        if(potionCollide == false){
            Destroy(gameObject);
            potionCollide = true;
        }
    }


    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        
    }
}
```

Just using global var. `potionCollide` . You created local variable instead of using variable global.

Answer (score 0):

Is your potion on the scene before you start the game? Whatever happens during runtime does not permanently change the scene, if you want the potion to disappear forever it cannot be on the hierarchy of the scene before the game runs. When you reload a scene it resets to the state it was before you ran the game.

Comment: Yes, my potion is on the scene before I start the game. I want it to disappear forever from the scene once the player collides with it.  I'm pretty sure this is possible, I just don't know how to implement it. Any thoughts?

Comment: Or, another thing that is possible to make my game functional could be this--the player collects the potion, dies, and the game restarts. From there, if the player tries to get the potion again, they shouldn't be able to pick it up. Is that possible?

Comment: if it's on the scene when the game starts then it's not possible, a way to solve this would be permanently memorizing on a save file if the potion should be there, and make a script to check if the potion should be there everytime the scene starts, if it should be, then use Instantiate(potion) to spawn it.

Comment: I edited it. I'm trying to use booleans to check if the potion has already been obtained or not but this doesn't seem to work. I think this is because when the scene reloads, the script also. What should I do? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, when the scene reloads, everything on it reloads as well and their values get reset, here's a pretty good tutorial covering save files on unity, i recommend you to read it fully: https://www.raywenderlich.com/418-how-to-save-and-load-a-game-in-unity

Comment: Looking for a less complex solution though. I just want a player to be able to collect the potion and then not be able to collect it anymore if the scene reloads. Any other thoughts since my game is pretty basic overall?

Comment: You could use https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.DontDestroyOnLoad.html on the script that holds the information wheter or not the potion was picked, Don'tDestroyOnload means that the gameobject with the script will not be destroyed when you load a new scene, so any kind of information it has will remain unchanged, including booleans.